# Programmatically Set File Write Rate

Tags: python, linux, filesystems

I want to be able to easily set a benchmarking program's file write rate. It's a python program that I'm using to test another system. I'd like to be able to control the rate of file creation. One method I have thought of is to have a function with an argument for the number of files to create. This could be called in a loop which keeps track of the clock and only calls the function every second. This would fulfill the requirement of creating a certain number of files every second. The problem with this is that there could be a chunk of dead time (milliseconds, but still). I'd like a continuous load.

Comment: benchmark is hard to do well (and flawed benchmarks are worst than useless); there are plenty benchmark applications out there, reinventing this wheel may be harder than you think.

Comment: I just need to create files to generate load on the application I'm testing. However, I'm actually checking the performance of the Linux server under that load. Although I will be checking spots in that application to see if performance could be increased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to somehow keep track of the time it takes to actually perform the file I/O calls, and adjust the sleep times between the operations. Adjustment needs to be continuous, as the sleeps and IO calls might take different amount of time depending on system load.

If you'd like to do N operations per second on average, you could run loops of few seconds (or longer), and after every round see if you're running too fast or slow, and adjust the sleep() time done between each operation upwards or downwards based on that. If you're running much too fast, increment the sleep time more, if you're only a little bit too fast, increment less.

```
import time
# target rate: 100 ops / 1 second
target = 100.0
round_time = 1.0
# at first, assume the writes are immediate
sleepTime = round_time/target

ops = 0
t_start = time.time()

while True:
    #doYourIOoperationHere()
    ops += 1
    time.sleep(sleepTime)

    # adjust sleep time periodically
    if ops == target:
        t_end = time.time()
        elapsed = t_end - t_start
        difference = round_time - elapsed
        # print out the vars here to debug adjustment
        print "%d ops done, elapsed %.3f, difference %.3f" % (ops, elapsed, difference)
        # increase or decrease the sleep time, approach the target time slowly
        sleepTime += difference/target/2
        t_start = time.time()
        ops = 0
```

Or something along those lines (simplistic code untested). This might not work well for very high IO rates or system loads, you might have to start doing multiple write operations per single sleep call. Also, a longer averaging than 1 second is likely to be necessary.